# How do I make the checkbox contain value :checked (boolean)?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I would like to make checkbox input to have dynamic value depending on :checked.

If checkbox is checked, then the value is "true"

```
<input type="checkbox" value="true" checked="checked">
```

or
If checkbox is unchecked, then the value is "false"

```
<input type="checkbox" value="false">
```

I'm doing this because I'm submitting form through ajax and I'm using jQuery.searialize()

This field is more like a switch.

Is it possible? Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need to do that? Are you submitting a form?

Comment: Yes, through ajax.

Comment: `jQuery.serialize()` should give you the value only if it was checked anyway

Comment: checkboxes are made to be used in a form. When sending the form, only those checked return the value they contain. if they are not checked their values are not transmitted.

Answer (score 2):

The jQuery way

```js
$('[data-switchval]').change(function() {
  $(this).val($(this).prop('checked'));
  console.log('current value of checkbox:', $(this).val())
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" data-switchval value="true" checked="checked">
```

[Postscript] Just realized this question was tagged as jQuery... here's the vanillaJS version.

```js
document.querySelector('[data-switchval]').addEventListener('change', e => {
  e.target.value = e.target.checked
  console.log('current value of checkbox:', e.target.value)
})
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" data-switchval value="true" checked="checked">
```

Comment: Thanks @Kinglish, I'm submitting a form with ajax and I'm using jQuery.serialize() so I won't know if a checkbox is checked.

Comment: Got it! I just updated to show the same concise code in jquery

Answer (score 0):

You can add an event listener for the change event.

```js
let checkbox = document.querySelector('input[type=checkbox]');
function setValue(checkbox){
  checkbox.value = checkbox.checked;
}
setValue(checkbox);
console.log(checkbox);
checkbox.addEventListener('change', ()=>{
  setValue(checkbox);
  console.log(checkbox);
});
```

```html
<input type="checkbox">
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question, you want to change the value of the checkbox depending if it is checked or not?
This can be done with AJAX.
You'll have to add an id ('#checkbox1') for your checkbox input.

Here is one solution:

```
$('#checkbox-value').text($('#checkbox1').val());

$("#checkbox1").on('change', function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
  $(this).attr('value', 'true');
  } else {
  $(this).attr('value', 'false');
  }

 $('#checkbox-value').text($('#checkbox1').val());
});
```

And then adding this in your code to get the value:

```
<div id="checkbox-value"></div>
```